# Mongodb/Mongoose in Node.js. Finding by id of the nested document

Tags: orm, mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose

For some reason I can't find a document when I search by the id of a nested document. I can perform other finds easily enough so these two work:

```
User.findOne({"_id" : some_id}, function(err,user){}
User.findOne({"arrayOfNestedDocs.value":someValue}, function(err,user){}
```

But finding by id of nested doc doesn't work:

```
User.findOne({"arrayOfNestedDocs._id" : some_id}, function(err,user){}
```

I can perform the search in a mongo shell so but not via mongoose. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Do your nested documents have an _id attribute and is some_id of type ObjectId?

Comment: yep they have an _id so I can perform the search in a shell fine (edited question to say that)

Comment: I guess it can be problem with `some_id` type. It should be mongoId, many peoples faced with same problem in different drivers. They are passing string instead of mongoid for example. Otherwise it sounds like a bug. Also mb you can show us your documents structure?

Comment: I am beginning to think it is a bug, the search will work in older versions of mongoose but not 1.4. Im confident the structure is ok. I guess I was looking to see if there is another way that is now recommended to perform these searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added it as an issue in the [project](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/389/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find an embedded document then the syntax is:

```
User.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, user) {
    var embeddedDoc = user.embeddedDocs.id('embeddedDocId');
});
```

Comment: But what if the top level document id is not known so we only have embeddedDocId to work with.